# Python reading Large png files degrades, reduces quality

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy, png

I have tried many ways in python to read, open and save PNG files to copy the original array data for further image manipulation, some with the size of 40 mb. But during the reading of the image, the image itself degrades, reduces in quality and size during the process. So I can no longer use that data array for further manipulation[ex. filtering] and further gathering of data[ex. psnr, entropy] because what has been read was no longer the original image.

> Using Pil.

```
from PIL import Image 

i = Image.open('shoes.png') 
i.show()
```

[Original Image| note I saved it in jpeg but the quality looks like it. 40 mb in png format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk119.jpg)

[Opened image from "i.show", 18.1 mb in png format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65G83.jpg)

> same with python CV

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('shoes.png' )
```

It yields and image of a bluish color.

So I don't get it. Does these libraries have limitations in how large an image it takes? Because I tried PNG format to secure no loss of image quality but then during the reading of the image, it reduces the quality during the process.

Can you answer the question about this issue, or can you suggest a better way to get numpy array, data of a large raw image or PNG image without degrading the image during the reading of the file and the saving of the file.

NOTE: also, when I tried to use the PIL code on a lesser image file, it did not degrade the image at all.

Comment: *"...during the reading of the image, the image itself degrades, reduces in quality and size during the process."*  Could you show us the evidence of this?  At what point is the image degraded?

Comment: When you use the PIL code `i = Image.open('shoes.png')`, what are `i.mode` and `i.size`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser. imgSize =  (4608, 3072)
imgmode=  RGB. but as you can see to the images i posted above. the contrast of the image went down. and the file  size to from 40mb to 18 mb

Comment: The images that you linked to are JPEG files, so they won't tell us anything about the quality of the original PNG file.  (JPEG is "lossy"--its compression algorithm loses detail.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is with the handling of large PNG files.  Here's a script that generates an array that is the same size as your image, saves it to a PNG file, and then reads it back using [PIL/Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/).  The output is shown after the script.  The result is that the data read from the file is identical to the original array.

To write the numpy array to a file, I use a library that I wrote called [`numpngw`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpngw).  Instead of `numpngw`, you could just as well use PIL/Pillow or [PyPNG](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypng).

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
from numpngw import write_png
from PIL import Image


# For reproducibility...
np.random.seed(123)

# Generate random data to use for the image.
data = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(3072, 4608, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
# Put a small white block in the corner
data[:3, :3, :] = 255

# Take a look at the red channel of a small subset of the image.
print(data[:4, :12, 0])

# Write the array to a PNG file.  I use numpngw.write_png; PIL and PyPNG
# are alternatives that could be used.
write_png("foo.png", data)

# Open the file using PIL (actually Pillow) and create a numpy
# array containing the image.
img = Image.open("foo.png")
a = np.array(img)

# Take a look at the red channel of a small subset of array.  It should
# be the same as the previous output.
print()
print(a[:4, :12, 0])

compare_str = "equal" if np.all(data == a) else "not equal"
print("\nRound-trip result: the arrays are %s." % compare_str)
```

Output:

```
[[255 255 255 106 214 113  73 224  83 164  68 195]
 [255 255 255 130  99  75  35 158 126 153 133 135]
 [255 255 255 152  79  15   7 101 175  68  45  71]
 [106 254  55  97 238  15  85 243  81 249  77  86]]

[[255 255 255 106 214 113  73 224  83 164  68 195]
 [255 255 255 130  99  75  35 158 126 153 133 135]
 [255 255 255 152  79  15   7 101 175  68  45  71]
 [106 254  55  97 238  15  85 243  81 249  77  86]]

Round-trip result: the arrays are equal.
```